# Swift JSON parse to array

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I want to parse the JSON data received from the server.

This is my code:

```
Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
    let resCode = String(data: response.data!, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8) as String!
    print("res:\(String(describing: resCode))")
    //print("data:\(response.data!)")
    let data = resCode?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
}
```

print res:

> res:Optional("{\"code\":200,\"data\":{\"hdl\":[\"81\",\"87\",\"65\",\"72\",\"81\",\"51.23288\"],\"ldl\":[\"128\",\"107\",\"150\",\"116\",\"168\",\"114.03974\"],\"tri\":[\"189\",\"187\",\"210\",\"192\",\"200\",\"171.26027\"],\"col\":[\"218\",\"203\",\"225\",\"213\",\"280\",\"194.59934\"],\"bmi\":[\"21.8\",\"21.8\",\"21.5\",\"21.8\",\"22.1\",\"25.28467\"],\"year\":[\"2011-04-20\",\"2012-04-03\",\"2013-06-13\",\"2014-05-26\",\"2016-06-08\",\"predict\"]}}")

I want to store each data in HDL, LDL, TRI, COL, BMI, and YEAR arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use JSONSerialization method jsonObject(with: data) to convert your json data to Dictionary:

```
let json = "{\"code\":200,\"data\":{\"hdl\":[\"81\",\"87\",\"65\",\"72\",\"81\",\"51.23288\"],\"ldl\":[\"128\",\"107\",\"150\",\"116\",\"168\",\"114.03974\"],\"tri\":[\"189\",\"187\",\"210\",\"192\",\"200\",\"171.26027\"],\"col\":[\"218\",\"203\",\"225\",\"213\",\"280\",\"194.59934\"],\"bmi\":[\"21.8\",\"21.8\",\"21.5\",\"21.8\",\"22.1\",\"25.28467\"],\"year\":[\"2011-04-20\",\"2012-04-03\",\"2013-06-13\",\"2014-05-26\",\"2016-06-08\",\"predict\"]}}"
let data =  Data(json.utf8)
```

---

```
if let dict = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [String:Any],
    let subdict = dict["data"] as? [String:[String]] {
    let hdl = subdict["hdl"]    // ["81", "87", "65", "72", "81", "51.23288"]
    let ldl = subdict["ldl"]    // ["128", "107", "150", "116", "168", "114.03974"]
    let tri = subdict["tri"]    // ["189", "187", "210", "192", "200", "171.26027"]
    let col = subdict["col"]    // ["218", "203", "225", "213", "280", "194.59934"]
    let bmi = subdict["bmi"]    // ["21.8", "21.8", "21.5", "21.8", "22.1", "25.28467"]
    let year = subdict["year"]  // ["2011-04-20", "2012-04-03", "2013-06-13", "2014-05-26", "2016-06-08", "predict"]
}
```